# disconnect ManagementScope

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm using WMI's ManagementScope. There is a connect() method but not a disconnect one. how do i disconnect from a ManagementScope? 
I tried using the "using" option but it's not IDisposable, and even if i'm out of the scope, netstat still shows me as connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you should change any property of the scope and it will be disconnected:

> "A scope is disconnected after creation until someone explicitly calls
>   Connect (), or uses the scope for any operation that requires a live
>   connection. Also, the scope is disconnected from the previous
>   connection whenever the identifying properties of the scope are
>   changed."

just as I have found here:

[System.Management - How to disconnect from remote computer?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/clr/thread/edf6c5d5-2a36-4232-baee-35df4bf19679)

Answer (score 0):

changing any properties does not disconnect it for my program. I changed the "username" in the Options.Username.
Only closing my program removes the connection.

This is an issue if you want to make x thousand connections.